# What are the differences between these two space-vim projects?

Tags: vim

What are the differences between these two space-vim projects?

https://github.com/liuchengxu/space-vim

https://github.com/SpaceVim/SpaceVim

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The point of all the SpaceVim projects is to take the hard parts of configuring Vim to have IDE-esque features away and introduce a sensible set of default keybindings; they’re inspired by the SpaceMacs project to do something similar for emacs.

More than one person has had this idea, and all the different implementations kinda merged, but I’d recommend going with SpaceVim/SpaceVim because that’s the one with (in my experience) the best documentation and the most useful community.